# How can i change the label names of the qpushbutton using pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here is my sample code, i try to translate the my entire file in to Arabic language using with python.i tried with the dictionary in pyqt4, when i click Arabic language i want to change the all buttons name and label name in my file.please can anyone please help me how can i solve this program using in pyqt4

Given bellow is my sample code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore

data = {'Arabic': {'Share': 'Aktie','Rename': 'Umbenennen','Back':'Zurück'}}
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sharebtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Share")
        self.renamebtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Rename")
        self.backbtn  = QtGui.QPushButton('Back')

        self.labelflag = QtGui.QLabel()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("./img/english.png")
        pixmap1 = pixmap.scaled(60, 60, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)

        self.labelflag.setPixmap(pixmap1)
        self.labelflag.mousePressEvent = self.languageWidget
        self.lay1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Light)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.mainLayout =QtGui. QGridLayout()
        self.btnSee  =QtGui. QPushButton('See_file')
        self.btnSee.clicked.connect(self.files)
        self.lay1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.btnSee)
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.backbtn)
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.sharebtn)
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.labelflag)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea,0,1)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.lay1,0,0)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,500)
    def files(self):
        self.w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.w)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.label.setText("helloworld")
        self.btnq = QtGui.QPushButton("click")
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btnq)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)
        self.show()

    def languageWidget(self, event):

        self.lanwidget1 = QtGui.QDialog()
        self.langvbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.lanwidget1)

        self.eng_hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.englabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.englabel.setText("English")
        self.englabel1 = QtGui.QLabel()

        self.engpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("./img/english.png")
        self.englabel1.mousePressEvent = self.engicon
        self.eng_pixmap = self.engpixmap.scaled(60, 60, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
        self.englabel1.setPixmap(self.eng_pixmap)
        self.eng_hbox.addWidget(self.englabel1)
        self.eng_hbox.addWidget(self.englabel)


        self.arabic_hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.ara_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.ara_label.setText("Arabic")
        self.arbiclabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.arabicpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("./img/arabic.jpeg")
        self.arbiclabel.mousePressEvent = self.arabic_icon
        self.ara_pixmap = self.arabicpixmap.scaled(60, 60, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
        self.arbiclabel.setPixmap(self.ara_pixmap)
        self.arabic_hbox.addWidget(self.arbiclabel)
        self.arabic_hbox.addWidget(self.ara_label)


        self.german_hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.ger_label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.ger_label.setText("German")

        self.germanlabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.germanpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("./img/german.png")
        self.german_pixmap = self.germanpixmap.scaled(60, 60, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
        self.germanlabel.setPixmap(self.german_pixmap)
        self.german_hbox.addWidget(self.germanlabel)
        self.germanlabel.mousePressEvent = self.german_icon
        self.german_hbox.addWidget(self.ger_label)

        self.langvbox.addLayout(self.eng_hbox)
        self.langvbox.addLayout(self.arabic_hbox)
        self.langvbox.addLayout(self.german_hbox)
        self.lanwidget1.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.lanwidget1.exec_()
    def engicon(self,event):
        print "englishh"
        global langIndx
        self.lanwidget1.close()
        self.labelflag.setPixmap(self.eng_pixmap)
    def arabic_icon(self,event):
        print "arabiccc"
        global langIndx
        self.lanwidget1.close()
        self.labelflag.setPixmap(self.ara_pixmap)
        self.change("Arabic")

    def german_icon(self,event):
        print "germannn"
        global langIndx
        self.lanwidget1.close()
        self.labelflag.setPixmap(self.german_pixmap)
    def change(self,i):
        print i, "iiiiiiiiiiiiiilanguage"

        if i == "Arabic":
            if i in data.keys():
                share_con_value1 = data.get(i, {}).get('Share')
                self.sharebtn = QtGui.QPushButton("share_con_value1")

                ex = Example()
                ex.show()
               #here i want to get the label names of the button how can i change and replace the that particular word 

def main():
    print sys.argv
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the pyqt.

Comment: sir  please help me now i posted my tried code here i want to get the push button label names instead of that i want to add Arabic language as i mention in dictionary  when i click the Arabic flag i want to display the my widget in to Arabic language

Comment: if knew any other methods  please guide me sir

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't even try to read the file.

get rid off all the QT stuff can go to console for now, Worry about GUI later.

Then for the translation. It's not an easy task. you cannot do a 1-1 translation because there differences in how the languages are spoken. best would be to use a translation api like  [googles API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/).

So for steps:

1. get rid of Qt and go back to console app
2. open and read the file contents
3. take the contents and call googles api with the text read from the file
4. get the text back from google 
   either print that to the console screen or write it to a file
5. pull Qt back in to create your GUI